Why does memset not store all values similarly in 2D array?
I have a 2D array set as
long long arr[500][500]

Running this main function, I get different values for m=-1 and m=-3:
int main(){
    memset(arr,m,sizeof(arr));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout<<arr[i][i]<<'\n';
    return 0;
}

for m=-3: it prints -144680345676153347 20 times, for m=-1, it is -1, as it should be. What is the cause for this?
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
using ll=long long;

ll dp[501][501];

int main(){
    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    //cin.tie(0);
    //int n;
    //cin>>n;
    memset(dp,-3,sizeof(dp));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout<<dp[i][i]<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}


Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Where is the array declared?

It's a global variable. Ok I'm adding it now

@underdog sizeof(arr) -- This is equal to 500 * 500 * sizeof(long long), not 500 * 500.  So just this alone shows there is going to be something "different" than what you expected.  This could also be your misunderstanding of what sizeof does.  The sizeof does not give you the number of elements.

Advice -- don't use competitive coding websites to learn C++.

To add to what @PaulMcKenzie said, contrary to what it seems to be, enum (class or not) E {} then sizeof(E) does NOT retrieve the number of enumerators, <some type> var[x][y] then sizeof(var) does NOT retrieve the number of array items, and for class MyClass then sizeof(MyClass*) or sizeof(MyClass) does NOT return anything regarding number of members, children, parents or anything of the sort related to MyClass. sizeof returns the size, not the count.

memset() is using the value m to set the value of every BYTE in every long long in your array, not simply setting every element of the array be equal to m.     A long long is represented using 8 bytes, so every byte in every long long will have the value based on m.

It's because memset sets individual bytes in memory, not integers. I'll just use the term "integer" below when referring to your specific 64-bit 2s-complement long long type(1), since the same behaviour applies to all 2s-complement integer types.
Using -1 works because it stores 0xff in every byte and it just happens that the integer value 0xffffffffffffffff is also -1.
However, -3 stores 0xfd and the value 0xfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfd is not -3 (that would be 0xfffffffffffffffd instead).
If you convert the repeating-0xfd value into an integer, you'll get what you're seeing: -144,680,345,676,153,347`.
Unless you know that a repeated byte pattern generates the same value as an integer (for example, 0x00 or 0xff), you're probably better off using a loop to set the values (the same way you print them), something like:
#include <iostream>

#define DIM 500
long long arr[DIM][DIM];

int main(){
    for(size_t dim1 = 0; dim1 < DIM; ++dim1) {
        for(size_t dim2 = 0; dim2 < DIM; ++dim2) {
            arr[dim1][dim2] = -3;
        }
    }

    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx) {
        std::cout << arr[idx][idx] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

This generates, as desired:
-3
-3
-3


(1) It's reasonable to assume your system has a 64-bit long long type because the 32-bit 2s-complement value for 0xfdfdfdfd is -33,686,019, which you are not seeing.

As an addendum to the answer from paxdiablo, I would suggest using std::fill as you are using C++.
E.g.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int arr[10][10];

int main() { 
    for (auto &row : arr) {
        std::fill(std::begin(row), std::end(row), -3);
    }

    for (auto &row : arr) {
        for (auto &cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << " "; 
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

Output:
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 
-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 

